# Serial Port & C Code

Tags: serial, uart, wiringpi

I have a [sensor](https://www.spec-sensors.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/DGS-H2S-968-036.pdf) connected to an ODROID UART (Basically an RPi just a different name for the UART port) and using the [WiringPi Serial library](http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/).

I am able to echo/cat to the sensor via two terminal windows and read it's data but using my C code I cannot. The sensor requires me to send it a "\r" to send back data.

```
cat /dev/ttySAC0
echo -e "\r" > /dev/ttySAC0
```

I'm wondering if my logic to write/read is wrong because the serialDataAvail (fd) is never true?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()
{
    int fd;

    // Setup serial port on ODROID
    if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttySAC0",9600) < 0)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
    }
    if (wiringPiSetup () == -1) {
        fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    delay(1000);
    serialPrintf(fd,"\r"); // send enter key to read data from sensor
    delay(1000);    

    while (serialDataAvail (fd)) {
            printf ("%c", serialGetchar(fd));
    }

    serialClose(fd);    
}
```

Comment: looks like you're forgetting to flush.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses. Looks like I messed up the serialOpen(). The brackets were done wrong. Amateur mistake.

Here's working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()
{
    int fd;

    // Setup serial port on ODROID
    if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttySAC0",9600)) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
        return 1 ;
    }
    if (wiringPiSetup () == -1) {
        fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    serialPrintf(fd,"\r"); // send enter key to read data from sensor
    delay(1000);

    while (serialDataAvail (fd)) {
            printf ("%c", serialGetchar(fd));
    }

    serialClose(fd);    
}
```